# Not able to create a service in acs- kubernetes after restarting all the nodes and master

Tags: azure, kubernetes, containers, acs, kube-proxy

service is failing with service-controller:

> Error creating load balancer (will retry): error getting LB for
>   service microservices/: Service(/) -
>   Loadbalancer not found

I've gone through the logs of proxy pods and its mentioned there that the service nodeport port is already in use, when I did netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN I can see that all my nodeport ports are occupied by kube-proxy

```
netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      2544/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1534/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      2122/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1233/etcd
tcp        0      0 10.227.80.10:2379       0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1233/etcd
tcp        0      0 10.227.80.10:2380       0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1233/etcd
tcp6       0      0 :::10255                :::*        LISTEN      2122/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32657                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::30002                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32659                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*        LISTEN      1534/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::31639                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::30841                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::30009                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::31322                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*        LISTEN      2544/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32000                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32001                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32003                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32100                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32004                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::30628                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32005                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32006                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32102                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32007                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32008                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32009                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*        LISTEN      2122/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32011                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::10251                :::*        LISTEN      9026/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32012                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::10252                :::*        LISTEN      2495/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32109                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32013                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::30542                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::32014                :::*        LISTEN      27041/hyperkube
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: yes, it is resolved

Comment: can you provide a solution or delete the question?

Comment: the above-mentioned warning was not creating the issue it was due to the other misconfiguration it was failing. can delete the question

Comment: so delete it, I cant delete your question ;)